# Is it possible to access route params within props to set a default?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I have a prop that I'd like to display an ID from my $route if the prop is empty, something like this:

```
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default: 'user ID: ' + this.$route.params.user_id,
  }
}
```

However I get the error that "this" is undefined. Is it possible to access route params from the props?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can actually pass a [function as the `default` property](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation):

```js
props: {
  name: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    default() {
      return 'user ID: ' + this.$route.params.user_id;
    }
  }
}
```